# Restcomm- Why does the port restroom is listening on 8080 keep not responding?

Tags: android, ubuntu, web, restcomm

I am completely lost and I've been at this for days! I'm trying to add restcomm to my android app for video calling capabilities. My app is already using a web server to retrieve content, therefore I wanted to add restcomm to my preexisting web server. After following multiple tutorials like:
http://documentation.telestax.com/connect/configuration/Starting%20Restcomm-Connect.html#start-restcomm-connect
and trying to install `Restcomm` through docker image and binary it still not working.

When I go to test restcomm out by visiting `http://'web_server_ip_address':8080` it keeps giving me `"can't connect to server"` or `"server not responding"`. But port 80 works just fine since I can visit the just the ip address `http://'web_server_ip_address'`. So I checked to see if the port was open with `netstat -tulnp | grep 8080`, nothing returned back and with http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ so no process. But even after I tried to open it using `ufw` add rule for ubuntu's firewall. It still didn't work, after starting the `Restcomm` service.

What I am doing wrong? I'm getting really frustrated. Any suggestions will help.